# migration failed can't quote hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 5.2 to 6 upgrade

```
    create_table :logs, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.uuid :trackable_id, null: false
      t.string :trackable_type, null: false
      t.uuid :owner_id, null: false
      t.string :owner_type, null: false
      t.string :key, null: false
      t.hstore :parameters, null: false, default: {}
      t.datetime :created_at
    end
```

but the migration fails saying

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

can't quote Hash
```

What is the patch for this

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the empty hash with quotes this way:

```
t.hstore :parameters, null: false, default: "{}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable `hstore`.

```
...
enable_extension 'hstore' unless extension_enabled?('hstore')
create_table :logs, id: :uuid do |t|
  ...
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#hstore can give more information if it helps.

Comment: hstore extension is already enabled even then the thing tends to repeat

Comment: can you share the code for the whole file, it will help eliminate suggestions that may already be addressed.

Comment: Sorry which i cannot do

Comment: not sure why that would be an issue, but is the active record version in those up to date? `ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]`

Comment: Yes perfectly being added

Comment: You mean that is in there, or did that fix something?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Yaml.

```
t.hstore :parameters, null: false, default: YAML.dump({})
```